# Open source web based too to document request flow

Tags: web-services, process-control, documentation

We are building an application which interfaces with multiple systems to complete a flow. For example, I have a REST service to get the list of users, then it has to talk to 4 separate systems to complete the flow.
With many such services like this, it's difficult for the team to document the whole application technical flows.

Is there a *open source web based tool* which help to document these in a visual manner where

1. we could create the request flow with the various systems in place
2. Include the service contract at each stage
3. Ability to test the service at each stage with request data

So this is more like a combination of Swagger + process definition tool.

Any suggestion, kindly help

[image: Sample Flow]